# Can we give hyper-link to a high-low line of a chart in MS Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I am searching for a solution to give hyper-link to a high-low line of a chart in MS Excel.

I have a chart where I am comparing two types of data

This is the graph which compares marks of two students

[image: graph]

What I wanted was to give a hyper-link to each of those lines(high-low line connecting two graphs)so that it will navigate to another sheet upon clicking.

But I was not able to do that . Is there any way to achieve this (Or is it possible for individual nodes e,g. clicking at the point (math,120) ?

regards

Answer (score 1):

If the chart is on it's own sheet then put this code behind:

```
Private Sub Chart_Select(ByVal ElementID As Long, _
 ByVal Arg1 As Long, ByVal Arg2 As Long)

    If ElementID = xlSeries Then
        If Arg1 = 1 Then
            MsgBox ("Series 1")
            ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "http://www.google.com"

        ElseIf Arg1 = 2 Then
            MsgBox ("Series 2")
            ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "http://www.google.com"

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

---

`Arg1` will be which series was selected while `Arg2` will tell you which point was selected.  You could use `Arg2` to direct people to different website based on which specific point was selected.

---

If your chart is embedded within a sheet you'll have a few more steps to get events working on the chart, see this [Microsoft Docs  Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb211434%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for more details.